# Incorrect/incomplete results from FQL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql, photo

So, I need to get the most recent photos from my friends. I tried running some queries from my code as well as from the FQL explorer at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

The following query never returns.

SELECT src_big, created, owner FROM photo WHERE owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by created desc

Perhaps not a good idea to use the WHERE clause on owner, even though the FQL docs do say owner is indexed. So, I modified it to:

SELECT src_big, created, owner FROM photo WHERE aid in (select aid from album where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())) order by created desc limit 2000

and that does return but only returns photos from 3 of my friends and the total photo count is nowhere close to 2000.

I tried restricting the results to only photos created in the last 7 days.

SELECT src_big, created, owner FROM photo WHERE aid in (select aid from album where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())) and created > 1361570941 order by created desc limit 2000

Now I get only 1 photo (obviously from 1 owner).

Then I tried the last 365 days.

SELECT src_big, created, owner FROM photo WHERE aid in (select aid from album where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())) and created > 1330639808 order by created desc limit 2000

Now I got more photos, but still not 2000, and again only from those 3 owners.

If I now loop through each of my friends and run this query:

SELECT src_big, created, owner FROM photo WHERE owner =  and created > 1330639808 order by created desc limit 100

then I get proper results, and eventually when I am done with all friends I have photos from 202 friends, and if I sort the overall result by created, those aforementioned 3 owners don't dominate the top rows. There are many owners who have posted photos in the top 2000 spots, so the previous queries are clearly returning incorrect (incomplete) data.

But the last way to do it (loop through all friends) is terrible for performance compared to the previous queries - we are talking several minutes instead of a few seconds.

Is this a known problem or limitation? Any workarounds?

Comment: Why are you thinking it would not be a good idea to use a `owner` in a WHERE clause?

Comment: Tommy, I wasn't thinking that. Since my query on photo with owner in WHERE clause never returns, I thought I should try an alternate method. I didn't mean to imply that I know using owner is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Facebook employee friend of mine suggested using multi-queries as in:

{
"p1" : "SELECT src_big, created, owner FROM photo WHERE owner = 4850 AND created > 1341203410",
"p2" : "SELECT src_big, created, owner FROM photo WHERE owner = 5569 AND created > 1341203410"
}

I haven't tried it out yet, but I am guessing it will be much faster than making an API call per friend.

He said he will file a bug on the incorrect results from my original query.